# list of even Integers

Tags: python

```
def even(start, n):
    return[n*2 for in range(1,n+1)]
```

Eg :- start `5` and want `7` numbers
If it is odd in want to add +1. Output: `6 8 10 12 14 16 18`

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

If for odd number you want to start from `start + 1` and for even numbers start from `start`, then you can try this -

```
def even(start, n):
    start = start + 1 if start % 2 else start
    return list(range(start, start + n * 2, 2))
```

Output:

```
>>> even(5, 7)
[6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
>>> even(2, 7)
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]
```

In the code, if `start` is odd it will add +1 to it and store that in `start`. In case of even, `start` is remain same. After that it returns a list starting from `start` and every element is 2 greater than the last with `n` number of elements

Answer (score -1):

If what you want is to implement a function that returns an array of consecutive even numbers greater than start, with size n, then you can refer to this code.

```py
def even(start, n):
    return [i for i in range(start, start+n*2) if i % 2 == 0]
```